# Erlang's public_key not found when Erlang is not installed

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, erlang-otp

I am making the "hello world" in phoenix .
But at the moment of creating the database the mint dependency cannot compile

mix ecto.create asked me to  install rebar3 to build :telemetry  and then :

`==> mint Compiling 1 file (.erl) src/mint_shims.erl:37:14: can't find include lib "public_key/include/public_key.hrl" %   37| -include_lib("public_key/include/public_key.hrl"). %     |              ^`

I've installed asdf, hex and  also :

```
$ elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.1.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Elixir 1.14.0 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 24)
```

But on my system no findable file with that name :

`locate public_key          /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-10-common/include/crypto/public_key.h /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-7-common/include/crypto/public_key.h /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-9-common/include/crypto/public_key.h`
What am i missing on do not know ?

Comment: Should be installed as part of your erlang install: https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/master/lib/public_key/include

Comment: The elixir --version showed erlang mention, i supposed it was instaled .
But `apt-get install erlang` is not showing "already installed"  .
I feel a bit ashamed now , but thank you nonetheless  .

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't implying you didn't have it installed, I'm sure it was a dependency of elixir. I'm just explaining where you'd find that lib, and perhaps the erlang install failed somehow and so public_key wasn't installed as it ought to have been (although also possibly you installed it quite recently and your locate index hadn't updated yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [smathy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152786/smathy) i realized that some mentions in the result of

```
elixir --version
```

wrongly induce me to think that erlang was instaled
for instance my error was fixed by :

```
sudo apt-get purge ca-certificates-java
```

which let me install erlang normaly with :

```
sudo apt-get install erlang
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Ubuntu? Looks like you need to install the [`erlang-public-key`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/erlang-public-key) package.

> I've installed asdf

The error implies that you are not using `asdf` to build erlang, but are relying on your OS's packaged version.

Comment: thx @AdamMillerchip but my problem was a tad more trivial  :s .
i'll keep that in mind though  .

Comment: I see. I think "module not found because language is not installed" with a resolution of "install language" is stretching the definition of a useful Q&A, but I guess it's valid...